# return statement dose not work with setTimeout()

Tags: javascript, return, settimeout

Why the `retrun` statement will not return `x`:

```
function getData(cb) {
    setTimeout(cb, 1000);
}

getData(function () {
    var x = 10;
    return x;
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because your getData function is not returning anything.
setTimeout is calling another function which is returning something. and that is a different function. JS returned value for getData long before your function inside setTimeout will execute.

Answer (score -1):

A callback function usually never return a value, instead the value is passed as an argument.

```js
function getData(cb) {
    setTimeout(function(){
      var data = 'Here is the data';
      cb(data);
    }, 1000);
}

getData(function(data){
  console.log(data);
});
```